# Intent triggering before dialog call, and dialog is not shown, and MainActivity is not sent out of foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a weird problem. I am trying to start an intent after showing a dialog , but when I tried with my code, it just started the intent *without showing the dialog*.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    first_launch = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
    context = getApplicationContext();
    welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);


    if (/*some condition*/) {


   //my dialog which should show and and user should click before intent is started     
        PasswordSetMessageDialog set = new PasswordSetMessageDialog();

        set.show(fm, DROPBOX_SERVICE);
      //  set.show(fm, DROPBOX_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = first_launch.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", true);

        editor.commit();


       //This should start only after the dialog is called and click on OK
        Intent lock = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),service.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(lock);

       //MainActivity screen should be minimized after intent is called
        finish();


    }
    else
    {
        Intent lock = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AppLockService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(lock);
        finish();

    }


}
```

Also, I want the MainActivity to **finish** as well, after triggering the intent. How do I do this?

**Note:** I have **also tried** calling the intent **from the dialog** (inside the *onClick* method of OK , which solves half my problem, but then how do I finish the MainActivity page from there?

**EDIT:** One more thing I forgot to mention, I am defining the dialogs in **separate classes**.

Comment: Whats the Problem in calling **finish()** in the **onClick** of the dialog **OK** ??

Comment: It complains: The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess `finish()` should work beacuse you are in the Activity instance ,I dont know why it was not in your case

**Or**

Try this

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            YourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then whats the Problem, You will pass the **Activity** reference to the Dialog thru the **constructor** while creating the **Dialog**. There you can finish the Activity with the Reference

Comment: Yes, you are right. I managed to solve this by doing getActivity().finish(); inside the dialog. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it the way you described in your note. Just make some changes-

```
PasswordSetMessageDialog set = new PasswordSetMessageDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Then, inside the click method of OK, finish the activity with help of the activity's instance which you are sending in PasswordSetMessageDialog class.

Comment: It does not let me define a constructor for PasswordMessageDialog with arguments. It complains that the constructor should not have any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To finish the activity, use this code:

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Then you can use it in the onClick listener of the dialog

Hope this helps